# Why Do I get this error on vector initialisation?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a problem with vector declaration and initialization in a
class constructor. I have a `Station.h` and `Station.cpp` files of a class and I recall it in main :

Station.h

```
#ifndef STATION_H
#define STATION_H

#include <vector>

class Station
{
    public:
        int num_bin;
        int num_staz;
        vector<int> binari;   //here already gives me error! Vector does not name a type
        Station(int num_staz, int num_bin);
        virtual ~Station();
        Station(const Station& other);
    protected:
    private:
};
```

Then I want to initialize the vector in the constructor of .cpp like that:

Station.cpp

```
#include "Station.h"

using namespace std;
Station::Station(int num_staz, int num_bin)
{
    this->num_bin = num_bin;
    this->num_staz = num_staz;
    this->binari(num_bin);      //here I want to create a vector of num_bin size
}
```

and then call it in main like that:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Station.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Station staz1(2,3);
    staz1.binari.push_back(300);   // error! class Station has no member binari
    staz1.binari.push_back(250);
    staz1.binari.push_back(150);

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Put `using namespace std;` in your `.h`, not `.cpp`. Although, as anyone on here will tell you; it's bad practice to use `using namespace xxx;`. It's best to just do `std::vector<int>` and not `vector<int>`.

Comment: @alteredinstance thanks

Comment: Why you don't use `in-class initializer list` instead?

Comment: Its funny how people easily downvote, if I knew all C++ things  I would never ask for help...at least I tried and not only waited for a solution of my problem from others....

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> this->binari(num_bin);      //here I want to create a vector of num_bin size
> ```

The function you need to use is [`std::vector::resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

```
this->binari.resize(num_bin);
```

It will be better to initialize the object with the appropriate size as:

```
Station::Station(int num_staz, int num_bin) : num_bin(num_bin),
                                              num_staz(num_staz),
                                              binari(num_bin)
{
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu, thanks in fact it gave me a compile error with my old instruction, now it seems ok

Answer (score 1):

`this->binari(num_bin);` This doesn't work because it is not an initialization that is why it doesn't work.

To make this work use it in `in-class initialization list`:

```
Station::Station(int num_staz, int num_bin) : 
    num_bin(num_bin),
    num_staz(num_staz),
    binari(num_bin)
{

}
```